# Get documents given a range (up and down, not between)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to get the documents that, given a date, obtain the closest to that date both above and below, I mean, greater and lower from that date.

Current code:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $match: {
    $or: [
      {
        "timestamp": {
          $gte: new Date("2021-05-27T14:40:46Z")
        }
      },
      {
        "timestamp": {
          $lt: new Date("2021-05-27T14:40:46Z")
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  $limit: 5
})
```

[image: Desired result]

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/INSYv8fhzix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think is there any way to do this straightway, temporary you can try the below query if it's really required,

- `$facet` to separate the result for old date and new date as per conditions
- old,

  - `$match` to check `$lt` condition
  - `$sort` by `timestamp` in descending order
  - `$limit` 2 documents
  - `$sort` by `timestamp` in ascending order
- new,

  - `$match` to check `$gte` condition
  - `$sort` by `timestamp` in ascending order
  - `$limit` 3 documents
- `$project`, `$concatArrays` to concat both arrays in single

The below process is optional if you want to format exactly what you need then use,

- `$unwind` to deconstruct the above array
- `$replaceRoot` to replace `docs` object to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      old: [
        {
          $match: {
            timestamp: {
              $lt: new Date("2021-05-27T14:40:46Z")
            }
          }
        },
        { $sort: { timestamp: -1 } },
        { $limit: 2 },
        { $sort: { timestamp: 1 } }
      ],
      new: [
        {
          $match: {
            timestamp: {
              $gte: new Date("2021-05-27T14:40:46Z")
            }
          }
        },
        { $sort: { timestamp: 1 } },
        { $limit: 3 }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $project: { docs: { $concatArrays: ["$old", "$new"] } } },
  { $unwind: "$docs" },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$docs" } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bNdPWD_-EVJ)

Comment: The problem using $facet is that it does not use indexes.. so for big collections is better using 2 queries, one for $lt and the other for $gte

Comment: I think it is a better idea to do 2 queries for big collection.